# Trim everything before specific words in t-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I want to trim everything before specific words in SQL.

For example if I have the below text:

*Action State changed to Completed by Test User (testuser@holdingplc.co.uk). (Change Date: 15/02/2019)*

I want remove everything before the words "Change Date:", so I would end up with just "15/02/2019)"

Essentially I just want to end up with the date from the change date.

How can I do this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Why do you want that? SQL, the language, wasn't built to handle text processing. You could find the exact location where `Change Date:` starts with `PATINDEX` and retrieve the rest of the string using `SUBSTRING`, or just retrieve the date with `RIGHT(,11)` but none of them can take advantage of indexing. If you use that in a `WHERE` clause the server will have to scan the entire table

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/functions?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: `right` of string for `length` of string minus `length` of string starting at change date...  but then... what happens if your text has "Change Date:" listed twice? or is that not an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try these methods:

```
--INPUT
DECLARE @yourtext VARCHAR(1000) = 'Action State changed to Completed by Test User (testuser@holdingplc.co.uk). (Change Date: 15/02/2019)';
DECLARE @yourword VARCHAR(1000) = 'Change Date:';

--METHODS
--1. CHARINDEX + SUBSTRING (Different Method)
SELECT SUBSTRING(@yourtext, CHARINDEX(@yourword, @yourtext)+LEN(@yourword), LEN(@yourtext));
--2. PATINDEX + SUBSTRING  (Different Method)
SELECT SUBSTRING(@yourtext,PATINDEX('%'+@yourword+'%',@yourtext)+LEN(@yourword),LEN(@yourtext));
--3. PATINDEX + LEN + RIGHT  (Different Method)
SELECT RIGHT(@yourtext,  LEN(@yourtext)-PATINDEX('%'+@yourword+'%', @yourtext)-LEN(@yourword) );

--OUTPUT
/*
 15/02/2019)
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `STUFF` and `CHARINDEX`:

```
SELECT STUFF(V.YourString,1,NULLIF(CHARINDEX('Change Date:',V.YourString),0) + LEN('Change Date:'),'') AS NewString
FROM (VALUES('Action State changed to Completed by Test User (testuser@holdingplc.co.uk). (Change Date: 15/02/2019)'))V(YourString);
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED to include a couple other ways using [TRIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), [TRANSLATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or Patexclude8K.**

Here's four ways to do this. Note my comments below. The first solution is a variation of what @Larnu posted:

**Option 1: CHARINDEX + SUBSTRING**

```
DECLARE @yourtext VARCHAR(1000) = 'Action State changed to Completed by Test User (testuser@holdingplc.co.uk). (Change Date: 15/02/2019)'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@yourtext,p.Pos+12,8000) AS NewString
FROM   (VALUES(CHARINDEX('Change Date:',@yourtext))) AS p(Pos)
WHERE  p.Pos > 0; -- returns nothing when 'Change Date:' is not there...
```

**Option 2: PATINDEX + SUBSTRING**

```
DECLARE @yourtext VARCHAR(1000) = 'Action State changed to Completed by Test User (testuser@holdingplc.co.uk). (Change Date: 15/02/2019)'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@yourText,PATINDEX(f.Pattern,@yourtext),11)
FROM (VALUES('%[123][0-9]/[01][0-9]/2[01][0-9][0-9])%')) AS f(Pattern);
```

**Option 3: [PatternSplitCM](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/splitting-strings-based-on-patterns)**

PatternSplitCM is always awesome for stuff like this and, though very fast, won't be as quick as the first solution. PatternSplitCM makes this stuff super simple though!

```
DECLARE @yourtext VARCHAR(1000) = 'Action State changed to Completed by Test User (testuser@holdingplc.co.uk). (Change Date: 15/02/2019)'

SELECT TOP (1) f.Item 
FROM  dbo.PatternSplitCM(@yourtext,'[0-9/)]') AS f
WHERE f.Item LIKE '%/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])';
```

**Option #4: Using [Patexclude8K](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/patexclude8k)**

```
DECLARE @yourtext VARCHAR(1000) = 'Action State changed to Completed by Test User (testuser@holdingplc.co.uk). (Change Date: 15/02/2019)'

SELECT  f.NewString+')'
FROM dbo.PatExclude8K(@yourtext,'[^0-9/]') AS f;
```

**Option #5: TRIM (SQL 2017+)**

I know you're on 2016 but I thought I'd include this for folks who thought `TRIM` was just for removing leading and trailing spaces...

```
DECLARE @yourtext VARCHAR(1000) = 'Action State changed to Completed by Test User (testuser@holdingplc.co.uk). (Change Date: 15/02/2019)'

SELECT TRIM(').(@.:ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ' FROM @yourtext)+')'
```

**Option #6: TRANSLATE (2017+)**

```
DECLARE @yourtext VARCHAR(1000) = 'Action State changed to Completed by Test User (testuser@holdingplc.co.uk). (Change Date: 15/02/2019)'

SELECT TRIM(').(@.:ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ' FROM @yourtext)+')';

SELECT LTRIM(TRANSLATE(@yourtext, f.translation, SPACE(DATALENGTH(f.translation))))+')'
FROM (VALUES(').(@.:ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ')) AS f(Translation);
```